# Promote own answer when editing other's question

Tags: discussion, edits, self-promotion

In the homepage I found two questions with almost the same title, edited by the same user (user A):

- [Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699403/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-webkitwidgets) (asked and self answered by user A)
- [1.Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013100/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-webkitwidgets-on-windows) (asked by unrelated user but edited by user A).

In the second post, he added a link to the first one (sort of self promotion). User B already mentioned user A post, without any link and claiming that it didn't help.

Is this acceptable to do this kind of promotion?

<sup><strike>I *tried* to anonymize the post to avoid meta-effect but if you feel like it would help to have URL, I can add it later.</strike></sup>

Comment: Links? A good example would help. Context is everything.

Comment: While I appreciate your idea to anonymize it, we really need the exact context here to make out what is going on.

Comment: It is quite correct to reference a duplicate question, we always insist on that.  Saves anybody else from having to note or vote as duplicate, the OP should have done this himself.  It cannot be promotion, the OP has already stated that it for some mysterious reason is not a duplicate.

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, it would be nice to edit the title to reflect the fact that it is not a duplicate, rather than prepending seemingly random characters to it... I would do it, but I know nothing about C++, QT, or WebKitWidgets.

Answer (score 1):

Editing someone else's question to include a reference to a different question/answer seems inappropriate (unless the user clearly intended to reference the link and simply failed to do so).

Commenting on the question with something like "you might find [this question] helpful" seems like a perfectly reasonable alternative that doesn't involve manipulating what the OP appears to have asked.